# Finding determinant for matrix using upper triangle method

Tags: matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

Here is an example of a matrix, and I'm trying to evaluate its determinant:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & -4 \\
2 & 5 & -2 & 9 \\
3 & 7 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

When applying first row operation i get:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & -4 \\
0 & -1 & -6 & 7 \\
0 & -2 & -6 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, if I continue doing row operations until i get the upper triangle, the determinant will be 14 (which is said to be the correct one).

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, if I instead apply this certain operation, R4 --> (1/-2)R4...

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & -4 \\
0 & -1 & -6 & 7 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

...and then carry on with operations, I get a different final answer: The determinant will be 7 in this case!

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Could someone explain that to me - is this operation illegal?
R4 --> (1/-2)R4

How so? Because i always tend to use it, just to simply things a little.

Comment: Please avoid use of exclamation mark after a number. It seems like a factorial.

Answer (score 1):

Different row-operations affect the determinant of the matrix differently.  Adding a multiple of one row to another will not change the determinant.  However, multiplying a row by some factor will lead to the determinant being multiplied by the same factor.

So, since you multiplied $R_4$ by the factor $- \frac 12$, the resulting determinant will be $- \frac 12$ times what the determinant of the original matrix was.

Answer (score 0):

You just multiplied a row with $\frac {1}{-2}$! This will change the value of determinant. What you can do is take $-2$ common from a row and write it outside.

Consider a $1\times 1$ matrix $A=[1]$.

$det(A)=1$

Apply $R_!\to2R_1$

$A=[2]$

$det(A)=2$

Can you see why you cannot do it?

Comment: I mentioned it in my first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If we  multiply a certain row or column of a matrix $A$ by some scalar $\lambda$ then determinant of $A$ changes to $\lambda|A|.$